# SQLite DISTINCT для одного поля в запросе с несколькими полями

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

Работаю с SQLite в Android studio.

Нигде не смог найти, как это делается именно в **SQLite**.

`SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2 FROM table EXCEPT SELECT column1, column2 FROM table WHERE column2 = 123`

**Могу ли я применить оператор DISTINCT только к `column1` но запрашивая при этом и другие поля?**

P.S. Мне нужно 2 столбца, первый из которых не должен дублироваться(при этом EXCEPT тоже нужен в запросе - исключаю некоторые записи `column2 = 123`).

P.P.S. Возможности Java позволяют решить эту проблему с полученными из SQLite данными, но хотелось бы узнать от знающих, можно ли

**UPDATE**

Например, как можно получить все эти поля в запросе, применив **DISTINCT** только к **chapters**?

**ID** в таблице уникальный, поэтому **DISTINCT**, применённый в запросе ничего не исключает из результата.
[image]

Comment: Возможно, `group by` по `column1`?

Comment: Что означает "не должен дублироваться только column1", если у вас есть пары (1, "abc") и (1, "xyz") и вы хотите что бы первый столбец не дублировался, т.е. была только одна запись, то что у этой одной записи должно быть во второй колонке "abc" или "xyz" ?

Comment: @Mike обновил(уточнил) свой вопрос

Comment: @Alexander Petrov обновил(уточнил) свой вопрос

Comment: Sql не может за вас решить какую именно строчку выставить при distinct. Чтоб отобразить другие столбцы нужно применить к ним агрегацию.

Comment: Если id уникальный и он видимо совершенно не нужен в выдаче (иначе бы вы наверное указали, какой из id должен быть показан) то и не выдавайте его. оставьте в запросе только те колонки, которые нужны

Comment: @Mike, я отображаю не дублирующийся список chapters, но хочу отсортировать его ORDER BY ID ASC, поэтому мне нужен в запросе этот id из таблицы. Это запрос на показ списка глав в том порядке, в котором этот список записали в таблицу

Comment: Вот смотрите, у вас "Имена существительные" есть с id 3150, 3119, 3118 и 3434. Предположим у вас так же будут "Междометия" с id 3110 и 3125 и 3164. Вот какое из них надо выдавать раньше, ведь у них id полностью перемешаны ?

Comment: @Mike  поле с id 3118 из таблицы должно выдаваться раньше, а 3119, 3150, 3434 должны обрезаться, по логике. Так и хотел бы

Comment: Тут самое главное правильно сформулировать задачу. Вы имели ввиду "вывести все уникальные chapters, взяв записи с минимальным id", на sql это переводится практически дословно: `select chapters, min(id) from tab group by chapters order by min(id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sql не может за вас решить  значение из какой строки  выставить при distinct. Чтоб отобразить другие столбцы нужно применить к ним агрегацию или оконную функцию.

Последний раз я использовал `max()` в подобной задаче.

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html

Также можно поэкспериментировать с оконными функциями и grou by

Comment: я правильно понял, что аггрегация возвращает просто числовое значение работы команды DISTINCT?

Comment: @zayn1991 конечно нет. в аггрегацию попадают значения, которые различаются когда совпадает значение дистинкт. в этом случае 3150,3119,3118,3434 и к ним применяется выбранная тобой функция. например max.

если колонка id вообще не важна - исглючи её из селекта и не надо будет применять ничего.

Comment: мне надо почитать про агрегацию. Ни разу её не использовал, спасибо